# How do we add MsTest to existing project with package manager console

Tags: .net, nuget, mstest

When I have existing project and I want add some unit testing there (maybe a temporary ones) for fast protoyping and I use nUnit I just do `install-package nunit`.

But I was not able to find how I do it with MsTest. Is there a way?

I can of course add manually a Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting  or create a separate Test Project that will all included. But wanterd to know if that is possible via package repos.

Answer (score 2):

(16 Aug 2014) the package in the accepted answer has been unlisted, but I found this: Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework/